# jQuery: Function call on keydown but get value on keyup

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to call a function on keydown but only get the value of a certain element once the key has been released? Basically all the other functions in my code need to be called on keydown except for one which needs the value of an input field after the key has been released. So to keep things simple I'd like to be able to have the default case in my switch statement call this function which then waits until the keyup event is fired.

Comment: I think, you will have to bind a keyup- and a keydown-handler to the same dom-element.

Comment: I figured I might have to do that although I was hoping I wouldn't since it seems like then I'll have to repeat my code to check to see if I should do something or not. I guess I'll do it that way for now and then change it if someone posts a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't wait for events, as event handlers only start while other code is not running, so you would have to store the information for that key somewhere and use it in the `keyup` event.

Note that each `keydown` eventually gets a `keyup`, but not necessarily in the same order, e.g.:

```
shift down
space down
shift up
K down
space up
K up
```

So, if you keep information from the keydown event, you would have to store it separately for each key.

Consider also using the `keypress` event that happens when a keypress produces a character, which also happens when keys are repeating when you hold it down.